# HTML5 Canvas fit to window

Tags: html, canvas, size

I'm trying to get my canvas to fit the page, when i do:

```
ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
```

It goes just over horizontally and vertically which is adding scroll bars.
the size its going over is about the size of the scroll bars are being accounted for before they're even there (just a guess) is this whats happening, how would I go about getting it to fit the page with no scrollbars.

Comment: Why not disable the scrollbars with CSS?  html, body {overflow:hidden;}

Comment: Thanks should of thought of that, will have to do for now :)

Comment: See example here http://bravenewmethod.wordpress.com/2011/08/28/html5-canvas-layout-and-mobile-devices/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Set the the canvas position to `absolute`. Also make sure there is no padding, or margins set in the containing element.

This is what I use on all of my full screen canvas demos.

```
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
canvas {
    position:absolute;
}
```

**[Full Screen Demo](http://cdpn.io/Khqio)**

Comment: Love it. Thank You so much

Comment: `canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}`
this works too, and it's always better not to use absolute positioning. (for example, if you use absolute positioning and the canvas is larger than the page then you cannot move up or down).

Answer (score 2):

The canvas by default is set to `display: inline-block`. Change it to `display: block`

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
canvas {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: this didn't work for me. (Chrome Version 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit))

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
function resize() {

    var canvas = document.getElementById('game');
    var canvasRatio = canvas.height / canvas.width;
    var windowRatio = window.innerHeight / window.innerWidth;
    var width;
    var height;

    if (windowRatio < canvasRatio) {
        height = window.innerHeight;
        width = height / canvasRatio;
    } else {
        width = window.innerWidth;
        height = width * canvasRatio;
    }

    canvas.style.width = width + 'px';
    canvas.style.height = height + 'px';
};

window.addEventListener('resize', resize, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I solved it by removing the `border`.